# Problem with compareTo and TreeSet

Tags: java, treeset

I'm having a problem with TreeSets removing a unit from a game I'm working on.  I'm making a tower defense game and the path is broken up into different blocks of a set length.  The blocks know the units within it and the next block on the path.  When the unit leaves the bounds of the block, the block removes it from its list and adds it to the next block.

I'm using a TreeSet to keep track of the order of the units in the block, that way I can tell which one is farthest along the path.  The units have a position field that keeps track of how far along the path they are, the higher the position the farther they are.

On some of my blocks I've noticed that when it tries to remove a unit from its TreeSet, the remove returns false.  I've used some breakpoints and I can see that the unit is actually in the TreeSet, so I think my problem is the compareTo method for my attacking units.

Here's my code for compareTo:

```
public int compareTo(Object other) {
    if (other != null && AttackingUnit.class.isAssignableFrom(other.getClass())) {
        AttackingUnit o = (AttackingUnit) other;
        int amount = position - o.position;
        if (amount != 0) {
            return amount;
        } else if (amount == 0 && this == o) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

One of the blocks where I'm noticing the problem is a block that the units enter the top, take a corner halfway through and exit the right side.  The block has two ArrayLists, one for units going from top to bottom (enPath) and one for the units from left to right (exPath).  Heres the code where I'm having the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < exPath.size(); i++) {
    AttackingUnit unit = exPath.get(i);
    unit.stepX();
    if (unit.getX() > rightX) {
        nextBlock.addUnit(unit);
        units.remove(unit);
        exPath.remove(unit);
        i--;
    }
}
```

The unit is in exPath and in units (the TreeSet), but units.remove(unit) is returning false.  Any ideas on how I can change compareTo on AttackingUnit to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compareTo method is strange. First, you should not have any elements in your list which are not of the right type, and also no null elements, since this will give problems anyway. So you could simply throw exceptions in these cases instead of returning `1`.

Second, as Steve already noted, the `this == o` check is not right - this violates the symmetry of your relation, giving you cases where your elements are not found. This gives this simpler version:

```
public int compareTo(Object other) {
    AttackingUnit o = (AttackingUnit) other;
    int amount = position - o.position;
    return amount;
}
```

Third, make sure the positions (i.e. the results of your comparisons) do not change while a unit is in your TreeSet. If the positions must change, first remove the element from the set, change the position and then add it again.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, I was under the impression that if compareTo returned 0 that the TreeSet would consider the objects the same and not add that unit.  I was worried about this because if two units occupied the same space the one would not be added to the tree.

Comment: If you need two objects at the same position be different, you need some other criterion to distinguish them, like the name or such. Just don't simply `return 1` in this case, as it is not symmetric.

Comment: The only fields I have for units right now are health, x, y, and position.  If they are all the same is there a way of getting the variable ID that java uses so I can see if they're the exact same or not?  If they aren't I could use that for comparing.

Comment: I think you want a different data structure.  Rather than a TreeSet, why not try a Map from position to Set<Unit>?  That way you could have multiple units at the same position.

Comment: I'll look at using a Map, but for now I've got it working.  I added an ID field for the units and changed the code for compareTo.  I also changed my code for moving the units so that it removes the unit and then readds it after changing its position.  This is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is in your `compareTo` is:

```
} else if (amount == 0 && this == o) {
```

You should be ORing them (or get rid of the `this == o` check). As it is now, two different `AttackingUnit` instances with a same `position` will return as 1 (first one larger). This will definitely give inconsistent ordering in the tree set.

By the way, you can replace:

```
if (other != null && AttackingUnit.class.isAssignableFrom(other.getClass()))
```

with

```
if (other instanceof AttackingUnit)
```

which is easier to read.